# Compiler unable to vectorize inner loop

Tags: vector, fortran, vectorization, intel-fortran

I have a very simple fortran loop, that sets some elements of an array to `0.0`, as shown below:

```
!dir$ loop count min(128)
arr(1:max(start,someVar)) = 0.0
```

When I compile the file with **ifort**, the vectorization report says:

```
file.f90(60): (col. 5) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
file.f90(60): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
```

I tried using `!dir$ simd` before the loop, and it vectorized. But my question is: Why wasn't it vectorizing, or converted to `memcpy` or `memset`? It is clearly an inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to ifort 15, the optimization report stated that the line was in fact converted to memset. I think the new memset code loops over the array, 'memset'-ing chunks at a time.